# Ionic Framework start error on Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a project with Ionic working fine in iOS (emulator and device), web and with a problem in Android.

I have used to create the project:

```
ionic platform add android
```

I open the project with Eclipse, everything is Ok, no errors, and CordovaLib is loading fine.

When I try to deploy in my device, I have this error:

```
    11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312): Process: com.ionicframework.congressapp251163, PID: 10312
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ionicframework.congressapp251163/com.ionicframework.congressapp251163.CordovaApp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2447)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:191)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.startupPlugins(PluginManager.java:114)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.init(PluginManager.java:92)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrlIntoView(CordovaWebView.java:383)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrlIntoView(CordovaWebView.java:368)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrl(CordovaWebView.java:344)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(CordovaActivity.java:389)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at com.ionicframework.congressapp251163.CordovaApp.onCreate(CordovaApp.java:33)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
11-20 15:22:56.350: E/AndroidRuntime(10312):    ... 11 more
```

EDIT:

The plugins have not been copying to the Android Project :(

[image]

Help please ;) Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem,but solved using this way.After creating the project first I build the project using the command `ionic build android`, then import it.if its not working try this

1.Remove the platform using `ionic platform remove android`

2.Add the platform again,and run.

Comment: Let me think about it

Comment: I had other project, and I needed to copy manually to the folder of the picture... but I don't like this solution...

Comment: Nop, I don't have classe.jar there... I have created the project again, and build later... same problem, in iOS works like a charm

Comment: Create  a fresh project and build it through command prompt not using eclipse,then try my solution.

Comment: Ok, now works... but I used two things, firt, ionic platform remove android and after ionic run android ;) Thanks bro

Comment: So my answer is helpfull?

Comment: Yes, a lot ;) I'm trying now in Eclipse... one second please

Comment: Two things more... I am creating a new project from existing code, and not importing the code... my mistake, I did not to do anything of your answer, if you want to edit with my comments, I will mark like accepted ;) Your first question was better!!